# Unable to run code through python file or jupyter (ipython notebook), working successfully through terminal python

Tags: python, odbc, pyodbc

I have this python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pyodbc
from pandas import *
conn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=drill64", autocommit=True)
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

which on running as a .py file aur running through ipython notebook gives me the below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/TestingDrillQuery.py", line 14, in <module>
    conn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=drill64", autocommit=True)
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/mapr/drillodbc/lib/64/libmaprdrillodbc64.so' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
[Finished in 0.4s with exit code 1]
```

On running through terminal python everything works smoothly, any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was able to solve it by changing permission to .py file
`chmod +x TestingDrillQuery.py`